# SASS: File to Import Not Found

Tags: sass, gruntjs, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to run some tasks on my project with grunt, but for some reason I'm having an error pop up when running a sass task.

This is the error I'm receiving:

```
Running "sass:dist" (sass) task
Syntax error: File to import not found or unreadable: settings.
              Load paths:
                /Users/x/Desktop/WordPress/wp-content/themes/theme
                /Users/x/Desktop/WordPress/wp-content/themes/theme/bower_components/foundation/scss
                /Users/x/Desktop/WordPress/wp-content/themes/theme/sass
                /Users/x/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/compass-0.12.7/frameworks/blueprint/stylesheets
                /Users/x/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/compass-0.12.7/frameworks/compass/stylesheets
                Compass::SpriteImporter
        on line 6 of assets/sass/app.scss
  Use --trace for backtrace.
```

My folders look like this, if it's of any help:

[image]

And my .scss file like this:

```
@import "normalize";
@import "settings"; 
@import "compass/css3";
@import "compass/css3/transform";
@import "compass/utilities";
```

It seems to @import normalize just fine, it's just having a problem with the `settings` file.

Any help with this is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You did notice that _settings.scss and normalize.scss are not in the same directory, right?

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normalize is a folder above `settings`. Did you try `@import "foundation/settings";`

Comment: I have. Still no luck.